# Combinations of ranks in ordered values row

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

I need to generate a code (preferably in R) that generates all the equal possibilities of how to divide 9 ranks between 3 independent groups (group sizes are 2, 3, 4). I have tried to come up with some ideas, but I can't seem to get anywhere. Can someone help with this problem?

I don't have any spesific values given. So there should be 9!/(2!3!4!)=1260 different possibilities.

none of my ideas worked

Answer (score 6):

```
x <- RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(3, 9, TRUE, 2:4)

dim(x)
#> [1] 1260    9

head(x)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
#> [1,]    1    1    2    2    2    3    3    3    3
#> [2,]    1    1    2    2    3    2    3    3    3
#> [3,]    1    1    2    2    3    3    2    3    3
#> [4,]    1    1    2    2    3    3    3    2    3
#> [5,]    1    1    2    2    3    3    3    3    2
#> [6,]    1    1    2    3    2    2    3    3    3
```

The columns of `x` correspond to the 9 ranks. The rows of `x` correspond to a unique allocation of the 9 ranks into 3 groups. The elements of `x` correspond to the group to which the rank is assigned for each allocation.

### Benchmarking

```
library(RcppAlgos)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  permuteGeneral = permuteGeneral(3, 9, TRUE, 2:4),
  comboGroups = comboGroups(9, 3, 2:4),
  Thomas = f(1:9, 2:4),
  Allan = {unlist(lapply(asplit(combn(9, 2), 2), \(x) {
    lapply(asplit(combn(setdiff(1:9, x), 3), 2), 
           \(y) list(first = x, second = y, third = setdiff(1:9, c(x, y))))
  }), recursive = FALSE)}
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>            expr     min      lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
#>  permuteGeneral    19.2    26.4    38.751    37.65    46.35    91.5   100
#>     comboGroups    34.2    45.1    60.819    61.20    70.80   152.7   100
#>          Thomas 10258.9 10986.4 12912.926 12099.50 14028.30 21670.0   100
#>           Allan 13314.6 14256.7 17343.145 15978.95 18749.60 35892.4   100
```

A larger problem:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  permuteGeneral = permuteGeneral(5, 15, TRUE, 1:5),
  comboGroups = comboGroups(15, 5, 1:5),
  times = 10
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>            expr       min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
#>  permuteGeneral  848.4244  853.683  962.7133  971.9733 1050.486 1127.023    10
#>     comboGroups 1279.6234 1391.748 1501.5075 1495.7773 1588.031 1713.698    10
```

Unsurprisingly, `RcppAlgos` is orders of magnitude faster than the base options. However, interestingly, `permuteGeneral` is quite a bit faster than `comboGroups`. Of course, which to use probably depends more on how you want the result formatted (ranks along columns or groups along columns).

Comment: This is excellent. From this, we can show that there is an isomorphism from permutations of a multi set of distinct multiplicity to partitions of unequal sizes. I will write something about this and be sure to credit you.

Comment: Yes, and, based on the benchmark, `RcppAlgos` appears to be using a different algorithm for permuting than for partitioning. Just curious--where will your write-up be found?

Comment: They are most certainly different algorithms! For permutations, we use something very similar to  `std::next_permutation`, and for partitions of a group… these are home grown. You can see a sketch here: https://github.com/jwood000/RcppAlgos/blob/f0ac079dbd016d47329b300f8ca1a1ab02f1c747/src/ComboGroupsSame.cpp#L3. Note, this is the outline where the group sizes are the same, but the idea for the general case is very similar. I might add that the general case is way more tedious to code.

Comment: As for the write up, I was thinking somewhere in the docs… maybe one of the vignettes. I’ve been thinking about writing a proper journal article about the partition of groups algorithms as I don’t think there is anything published on this topic.

Comment: Ah! I see now that you're the author. Well, thank you for an excellent package!

Comment: interesting that `permuteGeneral` differs a lot from `comboGroups` in terms of speed, cool!

Answer (score 4):

## An easy-to-use function

You can try `comboGroups` from library `RcppAlgos`

```
library(RcppAlgos)
v <- 1:9
sz <- c(2, 3, 4)
out <- comboGroups(v, length(sz), sz)
```

and you will see

```
> head(out)
     Grp1 Grp1 Grp2 Grp2 Grp2 Grp3 Grp3 Grp3 Grp3
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
[2,]    1    2    3    4    6    5    7    8    9
[3,]    1    2    3    4    7    5    6    8    9
[4,]    1    2    3    4    8    5    6    7    9
[5,]    1    2    3    4    9    5    6    7    8
[6,]    1    2    3    5    6    4    7    8    9

> dim(out)
[1] 1260    9
```

---

## If you want to play it as a coding practice ...

You can try defining a recursive function

```
f <- function(v, sz) {
    if (length(sz) == 2) {
        return(combn(v, sz[1], \(x) list(x, setdiff(v, x)), simplify = FALSE))
    }
    unlist(
        combn(v, sz[1], \(x) Map(c, list(list(x)), f(setdiff(v, x), sz[-1])), simplify = FALSE),
        FALSE
    )
}
```

When you run the code below

```
v <- 1:9
sz <- c(2, 3, 4)
out <- f(v, sz)
```

you will see the output (saved in a list)

```
> head(out)
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 3 4 5

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 6 7 8 9


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 3 4 6

[[2]][[3]]
[1] 5 7 8 9


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 3 4 7

[[3]][[3]]
[1] 5 6 8 9


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[4]][[2]]
[1] 3 4 8

[[4]][[3]]
[1] 5 6 7 9


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[5]][[2]]
[1] 3 4 9

[[5]][[3]]
[1] 5 6 7 8


[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[6]][[2]]
[1] 3 5 6

[[6]][[3]]
[1] 4 7 8 9


> length(out)
[1] 1260
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed colnames into c("a1","a2", "b1", "b2", "b3", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4") so I can distinguish ranks inside groups as well, because I need to calculate some probabilities.

Comment: Very nice as usual Thomas!

Answer (score 4):

If you want a list with all possibilities, you could do the following which uses only base R:

```r
result <- unlist(lapply(asplit(combn(9, 2), 2), \(x) {
  lapply(asplit(combn(setdiff(1:9, x), 3), 2), 
         \(y) list(first = x, second = y, third = setdiff(1:9, c(x, y))))
}), recursive = FALSE)
```

This gives you a list of all 1260 possibilities. For example:

```r
result[[500]]
#> $first
#> [1] 2 9
#>
#> $second
#> [1] 1 5 6
#> 
#> $third
#> [1] 3 4 7 8
```

And the object is of the correct dimensions:

```r
str(result)
#> List of 1260
#> $ :List of 3
#> ..$ first : int [1:2(1d)] 1 2
#> ..$ second: int [1:3(1d)] 3 4 5
#> ..$ third : int [1:4] 6 7 8 9
#> $ :List of 3
#> ..$ first : int [1:2(1d)] 1 2
#> ..$ second: int [1:3(1d)] 3 4 6
#> ..$ third : int [1:4] 5 7 8 9
#> $ :List of 3
#> ..$ first : int [1:2(1d)] 1 2
#> ..$ second: int [1:3(1d)] 3 4 7
#> ..$ third : int [1:4] 5 6 8 9
#> $ :List of 3
#> ..$ first : int [1:2(1d)] 1 2
#> ..$ second: int [1:3(1d)] 3 4 8
#> ..$ third : int [1:4] 5 6 7 9
#> $ :List of 3
#> ..$ first : int [1:2(1d)] 1 2
#> ..$ second: int [1:3(1d)] 3 4 9
#> ..$ third : int [1:4] 5 6 7 8
#> $ :List of 3
#> ..$ first : int [1:2(1d)] 1 2
#> ..$ second: int [1:3(1d)] 3 5 6
#> ..$ third : int [1:4] 4 7 8 9
#> $ :List of 3
#> ..$ first : int [1:2(1d)] 1 2
#> ..$ second: int [1:3(1d)] 3 5 7
#> ..$ third : int [1:4] 4 6 8 9
#> [list output truncated]
```

Comment: I love base R, cheers! And I also added another base R option.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some base R implementations if you are interested

- Option 1

```
f1 <- function(v, sz) {
    helper <- function(v, sz) {
        if (length(sz) == 2) {
            return(combn(v, sz[1], \(x) list(x, v[!v %in% x]), simplify = FALSE))
        }
        unlist(
            combn(v, sz[1], \(x) Map(c, list(list(x)), helper(v[!v %in% x], sz[-1])), simplify = FALSE),
            FALSE
        )
    }
    nms <- paste0(rep(head(letters, length(sz)), sz), sequence(sz))
    `colnames<-`(do.call(rbind, lapply(helper(v, sz), unlist)), nms)
}
```

- Option 2

```
f2 <- function(v, sz) {
    helper <- function(v, sz) {
        if (length(sz) == 2) {
            return(do.call(
                rbind,
                combn(v, sz[1], \(x) {
                    c(x, v[!v %in% x])
                }, FALSE)
            ))
        }
        do.call(
            rbind,
            combn(v, sz[1], \(x) {
                u <- helper(v[!v %in% x], sz[-1])
                cbind(t(x)[rep(1, nrow(u)), ], u)
            }, FALSE)
        )
    }
    nms <- paste0(rep(head(letters, length(sz)), sz), sequence(sz))
    `colnames<-`(helper(v, sz), nms)
}
```

---

## Output

Given data

```
> v <- 1:9

> sz <- 2:4
```

we can see

```
> out1 <- f1(v, sz)

> head(out1)
     a1 a2 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3 c4
[1,]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
[2,]  1  2  3  4  6  5  7  8  9
[3,]  1  2  3  4  7  5  6  8  9
[4,]  1  2  3  4  8  5  6  7  9
[5,]  1  2  3  4  9  5  6  7  8
[6,]  1  2  3  5  6  4  7  8  9

> dim(out1)
[1] 1260    9
```

and

```
> out2 <- f2(v, sz)

> head(out2)
     a1 a2 b1 b2 b3 c1 c2 c3 c4
[1,]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
[2,]  1  2  3  4  6  5  7  8  9
[3,]  1  2  3  4  7  5  6  8  9
[4,]  1  2  3  4  8  5  6  7  9
[5,]  1  2  3  4  9  5  6  7  8
[6,]  1  2  3  5  6  4  7  8  9

> dim(out2)
[1] 1260    9
```

---

## Benchmarking

```
library(RcppAlgos)
v <- 1:15
sz <- c(4, 5, 6)
microbenchmark(
    f1 = f1(v, sz),
    f2 = f2(v, sz),
    unit = "relative",
    check = "identical",
    times = 10L
)
```

shows

```
Unit: relative
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
   f1 1.930883 1.868502 1.895064 1.917045 1.879608 2.000789    10
   f2 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10
```